# 変化する関数の戻り値をどうやって取得すれば良いのか

Tags: python

すごく基本的なことで恐縮なんですがpythonでプログラムの勉強を始めたばかりの初心者なので、教えてください。
ひとつのスクリプトに２つの関数があるとして、下記のようにaという関数で、ｘの値を計算し、b
という関数でもこのｘの値を取得したいのですが、下記のようにxが変わり続ける場合（ｘは１秒ずつ１ずつ増えていきます）、どうすればいいのでしょうか？関数の戻り値はreturnで取得するとありますが、

```
import time
def a():
    x=0
    while True:
        x=x+1
        return x
        time.sleep(1)

def b():
    x=a()
```

Comment: bはどこで呼ばれる想定なのでしょうか。

Comment: こういう時はreturnの代わりに`yield x`とします。呼び出し側は`for x in a()`という様な感じでイテレータとして使います。

Comment: 問題と直接の関係は無いかもしれませんが、while文の中にある`return`と`sleep`の記述順はこれであっていますか？returnの時点で関数を抜けてしまう気がします。

Comment: 変化する`x`はどのように利用したいのでしょうか？（「時系列順のリスト的なものとして取得したい」等）

Comment: @tamo もしかして、関数 `a` と関数 `b` は同時に（並列的に）実行されるものだと想定なさっていませんか？